# Is appengine auto generated Long @id unique within entity scope?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Using objectify, I using App Engine auto generated id to create id for my entity as below:

```
@id
Long ID;
```

I put null in variable ID, so App Engine will generate the id for my entity automatically.

With Key creation through objectify function:

```
Key.create(java.lang.Class<? extends T> kindClass, long id)
```

Can I come at conclusion that auto generated id for entity without any Parent relationship is unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Each entity in Datastore has a key that uniquely identifies it. The
>   key consists of the following components:
>
> - The namespace of the entity, which allows for multitenancy
> - The kind of the entity, which categorizes it for the purpose of Datastore queries
> - An identifier for the individual entity, which can be either a key name string an integer numeric ID
> - An optional ancestor path locating the entity within Datastore hierarchy

The union of this components make a key unique.
Because of that the *auto-generate policy* guarantees that the ID is unique within the same *namespace|parent|kind|id* or only *kind|id* if there is no parent

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

Answer (score 4):

Auto-generated ids are unique for a kind and parent. For any given kind and a null (absent) parent, the allocator will allocate a unique value.